# Alkaline hydrolysis with KOH instead of NaOH. Why?

Tags: hydrolysis, chemistry-in-fiction

I really loved the series breaking bad. So I started reading about the science behind. I found this paper:

Harnisch, F., & Salthammer, T. (2013). Die Chemie bei Breaking Bad. In Chemie in unserer Zeit (Vol. 47, Issue 4, pp. 214–221). Wiley. https://doi.org/10.1002/ciuz.201300612

In Breaking Bad they [used HF to dissolve a dead corpse](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3KFzdBAngaY). But in the scientific paper they say that it is not a good way to do it. They talk about some other chemicals, I can't remember them. But they also talked about NaOH.

In Dr. Stone [they claim that sodium hydroxide is used to melt corpses by the Yakuza](https://youtu.be/2r9HEIJEX3A?t=92).

Reading a little on this topic I found a Wikipedia article. It is called [Alkaline hydrolysis (body disposal)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alkaline_hydrolysis_(body_disposal)). The article is about an alterntative method to burial or cremation. But there they use KOH.

I was just wondering: is there a scientific reason why they use KOH instead of NaOH?

Comment: KOH and NaOH are pretty much interchangeable.

Comment: Have a look at these articles: https://noahchemicals.com/blog/sicomparison-potassium-hydroxide-and-sodium-hydroxide .. http://info.soapwarehouse.biz/blog-0/bid/83765/Sodium-Hydroxide-vs-Potassium-Hydroxide-what-s-the-difference